# Build failed with D8 errors

Tags: android, kotlin, build

I can't build my application on my device in Android 5.1.1 anymore
Otherwise, I have no problem with Android 8 - 9 devices. 
I have this error during the build :

```
D8 errors : Class content provided for type descriptor net.nend.android.S actually defines class net.nend.android.s
```

**EDIT :** I'm a able to build if i do this

```
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

but some of the application's libraries seem to no longer work

Comment: I added proguard rules for retrofit 2 and that solved my problem.

Comment: but i still can't build without `minifyEnabled true`